# Load balance with Spring-Cloud-gateway shows fallback some of service stop/terminates for long time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-gateway

1) Spring-Cloud-Gateway(SCG) Started with load balancing with 4 microservices of same name, SCG shows all at services at Browser.

2) Closes/Terminates 1 microservice,

3) SCG shows FallBack Error for that service for longer time.

After some-time it doesn't show instance of that service.

I want that there shouldn't be any Time-Lag in that Service.
and that error-instances will not be shown.

Comment: What service discovery system are you using? Have you enabled retry?

Comment: Service Discovery-Eureka, Retry is not Enabled.

Comment: Is their any way to reduce the time-Lag?

Comment: Retry is essential in this scenario